# How can I solve this? 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: html, django

I'm making an Online shop using Django and trying to add quantity of each product from cart and it throws the error under :
`'int' object is not iterable`

I know that it should be integer in this code(this is my views.py):

```
def add_cart(request) :
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    cart = Order.objects.get(prod_num_id = pnum)
    cart.save()  # save 호출
    return redirect( "add_cart_pro" )

def add_cart_pro(request):
    memid = request.session.get( "memid" )
    cart = Order.objects.filter(order_id_id = memid)
    member = Sign.objects.get(user_id = memid)
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    template = loader.get_template("cart_view.html")
    count = 0
    for add in cart :
        count += add.quan + 1
    context = {
        "memid":memid,
        "cart":count,
        "member":member,
        "pnum":pnum,
        }
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )

def minus_cart(request):
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    cart = Order.objects.get(prod_num_id = pnum)
    cart.save()  # save 호출
    return redirect( "minus_cart_pro" )

def minus_cart_pro(request):
    memid = request.session.get( "memid" )
    cart = Order.objects.filter(order_id_id = memid)
    member = Sign.objects.get(user_id = memid)
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    template = loader.get_template("cart_view.html")
    count = 0
    for add in cart :
        count -= add.quan - 1
    context = {
        "memid":memid,
        "cart":count,
        "member":member,
        "pnum":pnum,
        }
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )
```

so I changed like this :

```
count = 0
for add in cart :
    count -= add.quan - 1
```

the error shows that I have an error at my last line.
`return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )`

and this is my template :

```
   {% if memid %}
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/member/mypage?user_id= 
   {{memid}}">MyPage</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/member/logout">Logout</a> 
   </li>
   <span class="fw-bolder">{{ memid }} 님 안녕하세요</span>
>  {% endif %}
   {% if not memid %}
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/member/login">MyPage</a> 
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/member/login">Login</a> 
   </li>
   {% endif %}
```

how can I solve this?

+) this is my traceback:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\BigData\Workspace\project2\order\views.py", line 107, in add_cart_pro
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 167, in render
    values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /order/add_cart_pro
Exception Value: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you show the error traceback?

Comment: I've left it below. Thanks.

Comment: The error isn't in that view it is '/order/add_cart_pro'   File "D:\BigData\Workspace\project2\order\views.py", line 107, in add_cart_pro
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )

Comment: I know right. but at the first line, it shows that it has an error at '/order/add_cart_pro'(I have two same views which has different name. add_cart_pro and minus_cart_pro)

Comment: Share the other view as well, point the line with that number.

Comment: I've added my other view and there are no error showing at the views so I pointed the line in my template.